# Maven/Nexus password with euro sign problem

Tags: java, maven, nexus

We have a user that's unable to connect from Maven to Nexus, because it always receives a "**Not authorized**" error, and we found out that his password has a **€ (euro sign)**.

During my analysis and tests to find out how I could set the password correctly in Maven's settings.xml, I tested the following alternatives with the password being 123456€

- password in plain text

  - <password>123456€</password>
  - <password>"123456€"</password>
  - <password>'123456€'</password>
  - <password><![CDATA[123456€]]></password>
- encrypted the password using the following alternatives

  - mvn -ep 123456€
  - mvn -ep "123456€"
  - mvn -ep '123456€'
  - also used mvn -ep only and then typed all 3 variants

and in all these tests I was unable to download the artifact from Nexus.

Is this a Maven or Nexus problem? and how can I overcome it?

Comment: You usually call `mvn -ep` and type your password interactively (not giving on command line) ... there is printed out some thing like `{.....}` which  you have to copy at the position `<password>{...}</password>`... not in plain text etc. ...

Comment: yes @khmarbaise, that's what almost all of our users do, and that was my first try when analyzing the situation. That's the 4th example that I put on the original question of the encrypted tries part.

Comment: The problem seemed to be that the euro symbol is from a specific code page (ISO-8859-15 ? If I correctly remember (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15)) which I suppose is not the same as the system is running on neither the System which Maven hosts nor the system on which Nexus is running furthermore it depends on the OS (Windows, Mac, Linux etc.) .... so I doubt that this will ever run... I think the same will happen with german umlauts like äöü etc. cause they belong to ISO-8859-1 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) I would go for the path as J Fabian Meier suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I would solve this problem by saying that passwords need to consists of `a-z`, `A-Z`, `1-9` and maybe some well-defined other symbols as `-_/()`.